# How to Send Email to Django Oscar Registered Partners about Order Placed for there Products?

Tags: django, django-oscar

I want to Notify Django Oscar Partners through an Email stateing that there products has Order from customers. here Customers might place order from multiple Partners for multiple product. how can i send list of order placed for particular Partner and send Email.

Comment: what have you try show code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this Code in Django Oscar `Order app` at the end of `utils.py` refer Django Oscar github. in `OrderCreator class`

my code is bad optimise/customize it as per requirements.

```
        if settings.SEND_ORDER_MAILS_ADMIN:
        # Send an email to partner based on order placed

        order_line_obj = Line.objects.filter(order=order)

        partner_obj_list = []
        for x in order_line_obj:
            if x.partner not in partner_obj_list:
                partner_obj_list.append(x.partner)

        for partner_id in partner_obj_list:
            order_line = Line.objects.filter(order=order,partner=partner_id)

            ctx = {'order': order, 'user': order.user, 'order_line': order_line }
            commtype_code = 'PARTNER_ORDER_MAIL' # Add it in CommunicationEventType Model
            try:
                event_type = CommunicationEventType.objects.get(code=commtype_code)

            except Exception as e:
                messages = CommunicationEventType.objects.get_and_render(code=commtype_code, context=ctx)
                # print(e)
            else:
                messages = event_type.get_messages(ctx)
            send_mail(
                subject="You have an Order # %s"%(order.number),
                message='Your Message here',
                html_message=messages['html'],
                from_email=(settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, u'Sender Name'),
                recipient_list=[x.email for x in partner_id.users.all()],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
    return order # Return
```